# Bluemix Embedded reporting Service - Unable to connect DashDB

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb, embeddable-reporting

I am trying to connect the Bluemix embedded reporting service to DashDB. After creating the package (specifying credentials for DashDB) when I create a new report definition, and select SQL query, it throws the following error... will be great if someone can help on this

```
[jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.17.29] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, or socket output stream. Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1). Message: Connection reset. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
Connection reset
RSV-SRV-0042 Trace back:
RSReportService.cpp(754): XQEException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSReportService::processImpl()
RSReportServiceMethod.cpp(258): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSReportServiceMethod::process(): asynchRunSpecification_Request
RSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(857): XQEException: RSASyncExecutionThread::checkException
RSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(311): XQEException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSASyncExecutionThread::runImpl(): asynchRunSpecification_Request
RSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(914): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSASyncExecutionThread::processCommand(): asynchRunSpecification_Request
RSQueryMgrBasic.cpp(289): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgrBasic::executeRsapiCommand
QFSSession.cpp(1181): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()
QFSSession.cpp(1179): XQEException: CCL_CAUGHT: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()
QFSSession.cpp(1140): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()
QFSConnection.cpp(1924): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSConnection::DescribeDataSourceQuery
QFSQuery.cpp(409): XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSQuery::DescribeDataSourceQuery
XQEConnector.cpp(289): XQEException: CCL_THROW: XQEConnector::send
```

Answer (score 0):

the port is wrongly specified in DashBD link --- use port 50000